# Who is using XML Schema 1.1 version? Which parser versions support it? etc

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, jaxb, xmlbeans

The XML Schema 1.1 version of very good interesting features that are invaluable for my use cases. However, it seems to be relatively new. So I would like to get your feed back on the below questions before I finalize my decision.

1. Which version of JAXB supports 1.1?
2. Which version of XmlBeans supports 1.1?
3. Does SOAP/WSDL support the 1.1?
4. Does usage of this is going to put constraints on the soap stack that the clients of my API pick?
5. Which version of JAXP started supporting this. I know JAXP has support for validating against 1.1 schema but not sure from which version.
6. Are there any other things I should consider?

Regards.

Comment: That's six questions. It is best to ask discrete questions.  It makes it easier to answer, and may be more helpful for people searching for an answer to a particular question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1 - Which version of JAXB supports 1.1?

The schema-to-Java portion of the JAXB spec (JSR-222) does not cover converting schema 1.1 schema structures to Java classes.  Starting from Java classes you should be able to map to the XML documents represented by these structures.  Note:  I am a member of the JAXB expert group.

> 2 -  Which version of XmlBeans supports
>   1.1?

As far as I can tell XMLBeans does not support schema.  There is nothing about it in any of the release notes.

> 3 - Does SOAP/WSDL support the 1.1?

I'm not sure.

> 4 - Does usage of this is going to put
>   constraints on the soap stack that the
>   clients of my API pick?

Yes, for example JAX-WS only supports XML Schema 1.0.

> 5 - Which version of JAXP started
>   supporting this. I know JAXP has
>   support for validating against 1.1
>   schema but not sure from which
>   version.

I believe it is JAXP 1.4 (included with Java SE 6) that began supporting XML Schema 1.1.  The version of Java with Java SE 5 does not.

> 6 - Are there any other things I
>   should consider?

Which features from XML Schema 1.1 are you going to leverage?