# Complex restricting logic in XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm triyng to create a schema definition and I have to describe the following scenario:

```
...
<DeviceParamUpdate>
   <Update>
      <ProcessorName>NPT Length</ProcessorName>
      <ParamName>UseFilter</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>False</ParamValue>
      <ParamType>System.Boolean</ParamType>
   </Update>
</DeviceParamUpdate>
<DeviceParamUpdate>
   <Update>
      <ProcessorName>NPT Width</ProcessorName>
      <ParamName>UseFilter</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>False</ParamValue>
      <ParamType>System.Boolean</ParamType>
   </Update>
</DeviceParamUpdate>
<DeviceParamUpdate>
   <Update>
      <ProcessorName>Finder Width</ProcessorName>
      <ParamName>CMinX</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>-500</ParamValue>
      <ParamType>System.Int32</ParamType>
   </Update>
</DeviceParamUpdate>
<DeviceParamUpdate>
   <Update>
      <ProcessorName>Finder Width</ProcessorName>
      <ParamName>CMaxX</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>1500</ParamValue>
      <ParamType>System.Int32</ParamType>
   </Update>
</DeviceParamUpdate>
<DeviceParamUpdate>
   <Update>
      <ProcessorName>B Width</ProcessorName>
      <ParamName>MinX</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>-1675</ParamValue>
      <ParamType>System.Int32</ParamType>
   </Update>
</DeviceParamUpdate>
...
```

where

- If `ProcessorName`=`NPT Length` then `ParamName`=`UseFilter`, `ParamType`=`System.Boolean` and `ParamValue` type boolean;
- If `ProcessorName`=`NPT Width` then `ParamName`=`UseFilter`, `ParamType`=`System.Boolean` and `ParamValue` type `xs:boolean`;
- If `ProcessorName`=`Finder Width` and `ParamName`=`CMinX` then `ParamType`=`System.Int32` and `ParamValue` type `xs:integer`;
- If `ProcessorName`=`Finder Width` and `ParamName`=`CMaxX` then `ParamType`=`System.Int32` and `ParamValue` type `xs:integer`;
- If `ProcessorName`=`B Width` then `ParamName`=`MinX`, `ParamType`=`System.Int32` and `ParamValue` type `xs:integer`;

and

- If `DeviceParamUpdate` with `ProcessorName`=`NPT Length` is present then must be present that with `ProcessorName`=`NPT Width`
- `DeviceParamUpdate` with `ProcessorName`=`Finder Width` must both be present or none.

Is there any way to force this type of validations in the XSD file? Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're using XML Schema 1.0**, you cannot express such constraints in the schema, but you could use [Schematron](http://xml.ascc.net/resource/schematron/) or you could check it at the application level.

**If you're using XML Schema 1.1**, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via XPath 2.0 using [**xs:assert**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions).

Comment: Sorry but I'm newbie of XSD world. What should I do to use XSD 1.1 instead of XSD 1.0? Can I integrate XSD 1.1 with java and JAXB? Thanks.

Comment: XML processors that support XSD 1.1 include SAXON EE, Altova, and Xerces-J with PsychoPath XPath 2.0.  As late as 2011 (and likely still), [JAXB doesn't support XSD 1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834664/who-is-using-xml-schema-1-1-version-which-parser-versions-support-it-etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since my knowledge of XSD are not good, I chose to check it at the application level.