# What are the alternatives to have XML Schema 1.1 support by JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, xsd

I am getting error while generating Java from WSDL.  I wanted to use XML Schema's 1.1 feature (xsd:assert). It is asserting if an element is available in the Web Service Request.

```
 <xsd:assert test="(count(InstanceDetail[@OrderCodeType eq 'OFFERID']) eq 1)" />
```

I am using Apache CXF v 2.6.1. I am getting an error while using mvn generate-sources option:

> Thrown by JAXB: Unexpected `<xsd:assert>` appears at line 200 column 3
>   of schema file:

Researching upon the error, I found out that JAXB only supports XML Schema 1.0 and this feature is available in XML Schema 1.1. If it is true, what are the other options do I have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is using XML Schema 1.1 version? Which parser versions support it? etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834664/who-is-using-xml-schema-1-1-version-which-parser-versions-support-it-etc)

Comment: If you read the whole description, it is not duplicate. I am looking for a solution rather than just an answer to the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, was not attentive enough.

Answer (score 6):

No, current version of JAXB does not support XSD 1.1. See these issues, for instance:

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-994
- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-967

**Update:**

Concerning the solution. Me personally, I'd run an XSLT which would strip all the XSD 1.1. features and return vanilla XSD 1.0 as the result and compile that with JAXB. Not sure how to do this technically with CXF, though.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is clear, but what are the possible solutions to overcome this?

Comment: @user1555524 Please see the update with a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use schematron (http://schematron.com/) on top of XSD 1.0. It's a bit tricky but by doing so you will have the conditional validation features of XSD 1.1 and compatibility with the XSD parser.